# Can't reinstall Mac OS X

Tags: macos

I have an old Mac and OS X won't start, it is stuck loading the OS.

I want to reinstall but it just ejects the DVD a few seconds after I put it in.

The Mac has an i5 3.1GHz CPU and 4GB 1333 MHz DDR33 RAM.

I don't know a lot about Apple computers, I mainly use Windows; any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried booting in Verbose and/or Safe Mode (hold Cmd-V for Verbose and Cmd-S for Safe).  Please post the results.  You may need to take photo of it so we can see what's happening.

Comment: This are from [safe mode](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Aq_YjQ2fZl5ziJdGgnP6Wg2xp0MVYw)

Comment: I managed to make it not eject the disk but it won't start from it, I tried entering from option + selecting it and nothing, it's stuck loading. same with cmd-v

Comment: is there a way to get the disk back?

Comment: It's best to post those pictures to the question directly.  But looking at the last one, I would be willing to bet that you have a failing hard drive.  You said this is an "old Mac"  do you have the original install disks?  If you do, boot from the second one for the diagnostic utilities

Comment: one of them is the installation disk, the other one seems to be for apps or something related. Can I change the hard drive?

Comment: Can you get the disk back?  Yes.  The question is, how much money do you want to spend?  A physical failure is not going to be fixed by software.  You will need to replace the drive and reinstall.

Comment: Try booting from the second disk.

Comment: I can't after trying to boot from the installation disk, I don't know now how to eject it if I can't do anything, anyway thanks for everything, I'll see how to change the hdd

Comment: If you post the model number of your Mac (bottom of the case) I will see if I can dig up some instructions for you.

Answer (score 1):

shut down the mac, boot it up in Recovery mode, CMD + R, go to disk utility, select your main disk, and erase it, format it as Mac extended, 
close that window, go to Reinstall MAC OS X, and then follow the instructions, thats the best, way to re-install, it will never go wrong.

Comment: It will go wrong if there is a physical failure like the OP added in his comments.